# How to render JSON to HTML in an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, json, templates

I am using `jinjia` as template to build a web site, I have HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class='a'>a1</li>
    <li class='b'>b1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class='a'>a2</li>
    <li class='b'>b2</li>
</ul>
```

Now I get JSON data from AJAX request, the JSON look like this:

```
data: [
    {
        'a': 'a3',
        'b': 'b3'
    },
    {
        'a': 'a4',
        'b': 'b4'
    }
]
```

The Output I expected:

```
<ul>
    <li class='a'>a3</li>
    <li class='b'>b3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class='a'>a4</li>
    <li class='b'>b4</li>
</ul>
```

There are many `ul` tag in page, how can I use jQuery or javascript to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this :

```
$.each(data, function(i,v){
 $("div#selectedDiv").html("<ul></ul>")
 $.each(v, function(key,val){
    $("div#selectedDiv ul").html("<li class='"+key+"'>"+val+"</li>")
 })
});
```